# nginx not serving one file, but it's serving another file just fine

Tags: nginx

There really isn't a better way to ask this question.

I have this nginx.conf and for some reason the css file is being served but the json one isn't.

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;

        # Here, we set the location for Nginx to serve the files
        # by looking for index.html
        location / {
            root /;
            try_files /app/bin/Debug/net6.0/wwwroot$uri /index.html;
        }

        location /_content {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location = /config.json {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location = /styles.css {
            root /;
            try_files /app/obj/Debug/net6.0/scopedcss/bundle$uri /usr/share/nginx/html$uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

The file is there but instead of retrieving it the index.html file is being served from the first `location`.

Comment: Why does the json block not have the try file line?

Comment: Check the access log and the error log. The access log should show you the URL being requested (i.e. `/config.json`) and the error log should say why the file is not accessible from `/usr/share/nginx/html/config.json`). Ensure that you restart Nginx between configuration changes, reset the browser's cache, and the user that the Nginx process runs under has read access to the file.

Comment: @AsadAwadia just one of my many many many iterations trying to get it to work. From what I read online, just using `root` should have also worked. I also tried leaving root out and specifying try files with the full path, using root with try files, using / as root and using full path, etc.

Comment: @RichardSmith no errors - it just returns index.html and the request log only tells me what I know: I'm requesting `/config.json`.